# How to run "geth"-console next to a geth instance that is syncing the blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum

Running "geth" will continuously sync the blockchain. I use a ubuntu server as ethereum node.

Now i want to start a second instance of **geth** to run the **geth** console for running some commands.

This will end up with:

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another
>   process

Is there any way to run several instances of "geth"? One for syncing, one for the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the second one with `geth attach` option .